# JQuery Ajax post html data to php and get a reply

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I want to post data from a span like the following, but on click nothing happens.
i'm posting '4' in the following span. I don't how to post this or the syntax.
Span.

```
<span style="color:#B00" id="PidClick">4</span>
```

Using this.

```
$('#PidClick').click(function() {
console.log('PidClick event:')
   $.ajax({
    dataType:'json',
    data: {data:Pid},
    type:"POST",
    url:"test.php"
    }).done(function(reply){
    console.log('reply is' + reply) 
        alert (reply.name)

})
});
```

and the php being.
//// also is my '.$Pid.' variable right? i'm not sure if this is right.

```
<?php
require_once 'db_conx.php';
if(isset($_POST["Pid"])) {
$id = preg_replace ('#[^0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['Pid']);
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE Pid = '.$Pid.' ") or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
$result = array();
$result['pemail'] = $row['pemail'];
$result['name'] = $row['name'];
echo json_encode($result);
}
}
mysql_close($con);
?>

Console Errors:- 
PidClick event: 'Type error: Type error'
```

Comment: firstly you have to take the inner text of the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to assign Pid a value like the others are saying, once we have a value assigned to Pid. Since in the PHP file you're trying to grab a variable named Pid, we'll want to pass it as such.

Here's the updated JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#PidClick').click(function() {
        var Pid = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                Pid: Pid
            },
            success : function(data){
                console.log('reply is' + data.reply);
                alert(data.reply);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('There was an error.');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Secondly, I wrote a little test case PHP file. Just to make sure everything works. Once again you'll want to make sure to keep your variables the same when passing them back and forth; in the jquery example above you'll notice that I used "data.reply" retrieve the information, in the PHP file below I assigned the data to a variable also named "reply". I also included some safeguard to make sure that the file is only accessible through an ajax request.

```
<?php

// only work if requested with ajax
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
        strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    if(isset($_POST['Pid'])) {
        $return['reply'] = 'The input was '.$_POST['Pid'];
    }
    else {
        $return['reply'] = 'No input detected';
    }

    echo json_encode($return);

} else {
    die('direct access is forbidden');
}
?>
```

Here's the html file that I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>pid example</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="color:#B00" id="PidClick">4</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure all your file permissions and paths are correct when trying to execute this example. In this case all files should be located within the same directory.

Comment: there is somewhat a problem i don't understand, posting var Pid = $(this).text(); using dataType: 'json', doesnt post nor respond to click, so i use dataType: 'html', and it works, but now i have to get json data back as a reply from php which returns undefined because dataType: is not json.

Comment: In this case being inside a click function `var Pid = $(this).text();` assigns a value of `4` to `Pid` which can then be passed to the php script and used in the mysql queries. And you'll need to sort through the returned json result to retrieve the variables needed. I'll add my html file to my answer above so you can see the complete working example I mocked up.

Comment: ok do that, accepted your answer already. 1 up for being active lol

Answer (score 1):

User `.html()` to get the inner html

So add `$('#PidClick').html();`

```
$('#PidClick').click(function() {
  var Pid = $('#PidClick').html();
  Pid = parseInt(Pid);
   $.ajax({
data: 'Pid='+Pid,
type:"POST",
url:"test.php"
}).done(function(reply){
console.log('reply is' + reply) 
    alert (reply.name)

})
});
```

Comment: data:{data:Pid} is not being post, i cant only get a reply if i echo something in php but if i echo $data it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#PidClick').text()` or `$('#PidClick').html()` for getting the inner text of the span.

```
$('#PidClick').click(function() {
  var Pid = $('#PidClick').html();
  ..............
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you assign the Pid value,

```
var Pid = $(this).html();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#PidClick').click(function() {
   var Pid = $('#PidClick').text();
    $.ajax({
       dataType:'json',
       data: 'Pid='+Pid,
       type:"POST",
       url:"test.php"
  }).done(function(reply){
    console.log('reply is' + reply) 
    alert (reply.name)
  })
});
```

[js fiddler example](http://jsfiddle.net/BKbtH/)